# zfs-auto-snapshot only snapshots frequent snapshots even when hourly, daily, weekly and monthly snapshots are set to True

Tags: linux, zfs, snapshot, zfsonlinux

`zfs-auto-snapshot` is installed and has had the following settings applied to it:

```
# zfs get all backup
NAME    PROPERTY                        VALUE                           SOURCE
backup  com.sun:auto-snapshot           true                            local
backup  com.sun:auto-snapshot:monthly   true                            local
backup  com.sun:auto-snapshot:weekly    true                            local
backup  com.sun:auto-snapshot:hourly    true                            local
backup  com.sun:auto-snapshot:frequent  true                            local
backup  com.sun:auto-snapshot:daily     true                            local
```

It's been half a week since it's been installed and when the snapshots are inspected, only the four most frequent snapshots exist:

```
# zfs list -t snapshot
NAME                                            USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
backup@zfs-auto-snap_frequent-2017-06-17-0645  3.06M      -   123G  -
backup@zfs-auto-snap_frequent-2017-06-17-0700  1.57M      -   123G  -
backup@zfs-auto-snap_frequent-2017-06-17-0715  1.43M      -   123G  -
backup@zfs-auto-snap_frequent-2017-06-17-0730   928K      -   123G  -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the documentation or source code.

Open `/sbin/zfs-auto-snapshot` and set your system default options.

```
# Set default program options.
opt_backup_full=''
opt_backup_incremental=''
opt_default_exclude='1'
opt_dry_run=''
opt_event='-'
opt_fast_zfs_list='1'
opt_keep=''
opt_label=''
opt_prefix='snap'
opt_recursive=''
opt_sep='_'
opt_setauto=''
opt_syslog=''
opt_skip_scrub=''
opt_verbose=''
opt_pre_snapshot=''
opt_post_snapshot=''
opt_do_snapshots='1'
```

The cron script in `/etc/cron.d/zfs-auto-snapshot` runs the command with the appropriate parameters:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

*/5 * * * * root /sbin/zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=frequent --keep=24 //
00 * * * * root /sbin/zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=hourly --keep=24 //
59 23 * * * root /sbin/zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=daily --keep=14 //
59 23 * * 0 root /sbin/zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=weekly --keep=4 //
00 00 1 * * root /sbin/zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=monthly --keep=4 //
```